# how to create an object refrence of a class

Tags: c#

```
newButton[row, col].Text = RNGType.getRandomValue(bingoLetters[col]).ToString();
```

here is the one line of code in my program that's been giving me trouble. It says I need to create an object reference. how do I create an object reference?

Comment: Done any _Googling_ today?

Comment: Put the keyword new

Comment: Who wrote the `getRandomValue` method?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably, all you have to do is to change your line of code from:

```
newButton[row, col].Text = RNGType.getRandomValue(bingoLetters[col]).ToString();
```

to:

```
newButton[row, col].Text = (new RNGType()).getRandomValue(bingoLetters[col]).ToString();
```

Alternatively, you could also keep on using the code as you wrote it... provided you can define the `getRandomValue` method of the `RNGType` class as `static`.

On a side note... when dealing with random number generators (`RNGType` looks like a custom implementation but still, this information can be useful anyway) it's always better to create a single static global instance of them somewhere and keep on using that one when needed:

```
public static RNGType s_Rand = new RNGType();

newButton[row, col].Text = s_Rand.getRandomValue(bingoLetters[col]).ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!